# Can the Nikon WU-1a Wireless Remote be made to work with the D3100?

Tags: digital, nikon-d3100, remote

The mobile app integrated WU-1a sounds perfect for my needs - anyone aware of firmware upgrades or other avenues that would allow use with the D3100?  I am not equipped/inclined to pursue serious hacking.

Answer (score 1):

This is the list of cameras compatible with the WU-1a, [via Nikon](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Wireless/27081/WU-1a-Wireless-Mobile-Adapter.html?cid=prt-0512-wu1a#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-CompatibleWith):

- Coolpix A
- Coolpix P330
- Coolpix P520
- D3200
- D5200
- D7100

So at this time the D3100 is not compatible with the WU-1a.

Comment: Are the D3200, D5200, and D7100 considered part of the *Coolpix* line?

Comment: @Michael Clark - instead of posting a smart comment, you could ya know, click "edit" or "help improve this answer".  I think you know the addition of Coolpix was in error. Feel free to correct it, this is a wiki site.

Comment: Okay gents, that's done.

Comment: @dpollitt - You can make edits to your answer which take immediate effect. Although I can no longer find the FAQ that lists it, edits made by a user with reputation below a certain threshold requires approval from two other users before it takes effect. I was just trying to streamline the process by allowing you the opportunity to make your own edit.

Comment: thanks - but was looking for a possible work around